# Select First Element by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is My HTML Dom

```
<dd>
   <div class="Addable Files">
     <div style="margin:5px;">
       <select name="Kind" id="kind">
         <option value="1" >K1</option>
         <option value="2" >K2</option>
         <option value="3" >K3</option>
      </select>

     <div class="customfile">
       <span aria-hidden="true" class="customfile-button button">Browse</span>
       <input type="file" name="Files" class="fileupload customfile-input">
     </div>
    <select name="yap">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<input type="button" value="new" style="margin-top:5px;" class="AddNewE button red" id="AddFiles">
</dd>
```

And my Script:

```
//Add new Addable div
$('.AddNewE').click(function () {


    var Target = $('.Addable.Files:first');
    var CloneTarget = $(Target).clone();
    CloneTarget.insertAfter('.Addable.Files:last');


    $(Target).find('select').each(function () {
        $(this).css('color', 'red');

    });
});
```

So I expect when I click add button just first two select (two select of first div) be Red and all other selects don't changed, but I see weird behavior, In first Add everything is OK, but then in each Add all selects be red except second one, I think `Target` is first `div` and also I select Target's `Select` elements so why all `select`s be Red? where is my problem?

**EDIT**

I am sorry about wrong script, but this is my actual script:

```
//Add new Addable div
$('.AddNewE').click(function () {

    var Target = $('.Addable.Files:first');
    var CloneTarget = $(Target).clone();
    CloneTarget.insertAfter('.Addable.Files:last');
    $(CloneTarget).css('color', 'green');

    $(Target).find('select').each(function () {
        $(this).css('color', 'red');

    });
});
```

Comment: The way I understand it, your code works the way you've described that you intend, [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eDMyX/), no?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5mhmd/ works ok :o

Comment: Subtly editing your question within the first 5 minutes is annoying. You originally had `$('.select').css('color', 'gray');`.

Comment: @thirtydot I am sorry, your right, I think I found my fault, that's embarrassment

Answer (score 5):

This is achievable just by changing your function slightly. Try:

```
$('.AddNewE').click(function () {

    var Target = $('.Addable.Files');
    var CloneTarget = $(Target).first().clone();
    CloneTarget.insertAfter('.Addable.Files:last');

    $('select').css('color', 'gray');
        $(Target).find('select').each(function () {
        $(this).css('color', 'red');
    });
});​
```

To summarise the points I have changed, I have edited your `Target` variable to target *all* of the `.Files` items, then changed the `CloneTarget` to only clone the first `.Files` target. That way, when it comes to changing them all to red you're actually changing *all* the existing `.Files` items **except** the new one you're adding.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/usZPN/

Answer (score 1):

Your select is on `.Addable.Files:first` which selects the first select with that name, didn't you want to select the first div underneath like so: `.Addable.Files > div:first-child`?

Answer (score 1):

Worksforme in http://jsfiddle.net/Y2XhV/, although I'm not sure which `<div>` you want to clone: the one with the margin or the one with the 2 classes? Your selectors are for the latter case. Yet, there are some small improvements to your code making it simpler:

```
//Add new Addable div
$('.AddNewE').click(function () {

    var $Target = $('.Addable.Files:first');
    var $CloneTarget = $Target.clone();
    $CloneTarget.insertAfter('.Addable.Files:last');

    $Target.find('select').css('color', 'red');
});
```

You don't need to recreate new jQuery objects from `Target` when you already have one, and `.css()` doesn't need a `each`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the following fiddle solves your purpose.

http://jsfiddle.net/meetravi/9ehAF/

I am finding a bug in the code you have written in the following line.

```
 $('.select').css('color', 'gray');
```

There is no select class in your code rather the code should be

```
$('select').css('color', 'gray');
```